# Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file build.gradle

Tags: mapbox

Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'

on adding
mapbox configuration

```
dependencyResolutionManagement {

    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)

    repositories {

        google()

        mavenCentral()

        maven {

            url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'


            authentication {

                basic(BasicAuthentication)

            }


            credentials {
                // Do not change the username below.
                // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).

                username = "mapbox"
                // Use the secret token you stored in gradle.properties as the password

                password = MAPBOX_DOWNLOADS_TOKEN

            }

        }

    }

}


    compileOptions {
     

   sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
     
   targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    
}
```

make a proper build for mapbox v5 to implement mapboxs